# Difference between the terms OpenMPI and MPI API from output of mpi_info

Tags: mpi, openmpi

when I type `ompi_info` on my terminal, I get a huge output on my terminal buffer, a part of which looks like :

```
Package: Open MPI buildd@lgw01-57 Distribution
Open MPI: 1.10.2
Open MPI repo revision: v1.10.1-145-g799148f
Open MPI release date: Jan 21, 2016
Open RTE: 1.10.2
Open RTE repo revision: v1.10.1-145-g799148f
Open RTE release date: Jan 21, 2016
OPAL: 1.10.2
OPAL repo revision: v1.10.1-145-g799148f
OPAL release date: Jan 21, 2016
MPI API: 3.0.0
Ident string: 1.10.2
Prefix: /usr
Configured architecture: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Configure host: lgw01-57
Configured by: buildd
```

Ignoring the info on *release dates*, I am curious specifically about the meaning of  second line: `Open MPI : 1.10.2` and line number twelve: `MPI API : 3.0.0` . Does it mean the new functions from Open MPI version 3.0.0 available on the MPI version 1.10.2 ?

Comment: In your last sentence, I guess you swapped MPI and Open MPI.

Comment: I am sure I did not. It is the same as the output from my terminal shown above

Comment: Open MPI 1.10.2 implements the MPI 3.0 standard, not the other way around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question, it seems yes, the stable version of OpenMPI 1.10 supports most of the new features introduced in MPI 3 . [This page of OpenMPI-1.10.1](http://www.open-mpi.de/doc/v1.10/) shows the list of all MPI API's available which includes the API for one sided communication, which was introduced in MPI version 2.0, and features of MPI 3.0 like non-blocking collective operations like `MPI_Ibcast` and matching probes like `MPI_Mprobe` and `MPI_Mrecv`.

Although this list also doesn't contain the `MPI_T` tool interface and many other features which is available in the [current stable release of openMPI-3.0](http://www.open-mpi.de/doc/v3.0/) .

Comment: By the way, Open MPI 1.10 is no more supported. You should consider upgrading to the latest 2.1 or 3.0 series.

Answer (score 0):

[Open MPI](https://www.open-mpi.org) is an implementation (e.g. code) of the [MPI Standard](http://mpi-forum.org/docs/) (e.g. pdf document).

These are two distinct things that have their own and independent versions.

Comment: is implementation the part of API ?

Comment: Long story short, API = PDF + header files. Implementation = library built from sources. Note PDF is the same regardless the implementation (Open MPI, MPICH, ...) but header files are not inter operable.